# Faster way to fetch a single data from db with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi want to get only one column from one result from my database. So i do it in this way

```
$this->db->select('myclolumn')->where('id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
$temp=$query->row_array();
$finalresult=$temp['mycolumn'];
```

Maybe there is a easier or faster way to do the same?

Comment: Explain what is the actual problem.

Comment: there is no problem, i ask myself if there is a faster way to get the 'mycolumn' into the $finalresult something like $temp=$query->result->mycolumn

Comment: use `row()` instead of `row_array()`. Then you can use `$finalresult->columnName`

Comment: @DanishAli that's what i'm looking for - thanks a lot.

Comment: What are the chances that this is an under-researched duplicate question? Please search before asking.

Comment: @Danish do not intentionally break SO page structure by commenting solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so based on DanishAli's comment

```
$this->db->select('myclolumn')->where('id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
$finalresult=$query->row()->mycloumn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$finalresult = $this->db->select('myclolumn')
                        ->where('id',$id)
                        ->get('mytable')->row()
                        ->mycolumn;
```

All in only one command instead of a lot of variables and extra code.

In case you need to provide a default value if the row is null, break the command to:

```
$row = $this->db->select('myclolumn')
                        ->where('id',$id)
                        ->get('mytable')
                        ->row();
$finalresult = ($row)?$row->mycolumn:'your default value';
```